# How to send Asynchronous AJAX call to serverside in JQuery validation plugin addmethod()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

I am currently working on a task to deliver own framework using JQuery validation plugin that I need to validate CRUD forms client-side as well as server-side.And It's important that forms are not static thus created dynamically by "handlebar.js".

So I mapped client side validations when input fields created with class.

Eg -

```html
<form id="form-asset-create">
  <input type="text" class="my own custom validation for client side" />
</form>
```

I have custom method for client side validation to call server side and check the created asset is already added or not.But I need to send this AJAX call asynchronously when user inputs the data.
here below

And I have a javascript file called clientsideValidation.js to have those validations on client side.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("isUniqueField", function(value, element) {
  var elementname = element.getAttribute('name');
  var data = '%22name%22 : %22' + value + '%22';
  var result = false;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: caramel.url("/apis/assets?type=gadget&q=" + data),
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
      result = data.list.length <= 0;
      $.validator.messages.isUniqueField = "The " + elementname + " already taken";
    },
    error: function(xhr, thrownError) {
      console.log("error " + xhr.responseText + "  " + thrownError);
    }
  });
  return result;
}, $.validator.messages.isUniqueField);
```

I have tried this way but I cant get the proper error message while I have the property like `async : true` , as well as when I change it to false it is working fine.
Can anyone suggest me a good way to approach this task.Is there any way to send ajax request asynchronously in custom validation method.

I have to call the validation of client side when form is ready and when the submit button clicked to create a asset.

`$('#form-asset-create').validate();`

Suggestion would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: There is a method built into the plugin called `remote` that already does this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate form on submit by using if condition.

**For Example**

```
$('#form-asset-create').on('submit', function(){
  if($('#form-asset-create').valid()){
      /* START YOUR AJAX CALL OR FURTHER PROCESS HERE*/
  }
});
```

You have to add class for your required validation and its message to dynamically created textbox.

**For i.e.**

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control required email isUniqueField" data-msg-required="This field is required." data-msg-email="Please enter valid Email."   data-msg-isUniqueField="Please enter Unique value." placeholder="Email  *" value="">
```

Comment: I need to validate only some of fields in form and also I cannot predict the fields that will be generate dynamically.So How can I define ajax call inside the above method you suggest.Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: I don't see how this answer addresses the OP's question about using an async Ajax call as part of the validation process.

Comment: in dynamically created text box he only need to add class **"isUniqueField"** after that he define custom message using **data-msg-isUniqueField** if he wants. then when ever `$('#form-asset-create').valid()` called it will validate the all validation given to form input elements

Comment: we cant add validation message like this as I have using jqueryvalidation plugin addMethod I could only add validation to class when field is created dynamically.I have followed this http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod